# Auto adjust image using javascript attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so I want to build an web app where can upload image

how to adjust the image size in javascript? because i want them showed up in page

```
<br />
<input type="file" onchange="showImage(this);" accept="image/png" name="file"/>
<br />
<img id="image" src="../Assets/noimage.png" height="300" width="300"/>
<br />
```

and here's my javascript code

```
if (input.files && input.files[0] && input.files[0].size >= parseFloat('@ViewBag.size')) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (e) {
    $('#image')
    .attr('src', e.target.result)
    .width(300)
    .height(300);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
```

width and height in `<img>` tag set to 300 for default image

and after uploading image, it will set to `300x300` because of javascript's 
`$(#image)` attribute.

but, how to set its width and height using `max-height`, and auto adjust width? because uploaded image may have different resolution, and set it to `300x300` will make the image looks bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** and set `max-height` or `max-width` as you want:

**In Action:**

```js
$('#image')
  .attr('src', 'http://koncha.890m.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/2.jpg')
  .css({
    'width': 'auto',
    'height': 'auto',
    'max-height': 300 // your desire number
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="image" src="../Assets/noimage.png" height="300" width="300" />
```

**In your code:**

```
if (input.files && input.files[0] && input.files[0].size >= parseFloat('@ViewBag.size')) {
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(e) {
    $('#image')
      .attr('src', e.target.result)
      .css({
        'width': 'auto',
        'height': 'auto',
        'max-height': 300 // your desire number
      });

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
```